# When using a simple MySQL statements through PHP, is it better to target SELF or to target an external script?

Tags: php, mysql, html, content-management-system

Basically I'm building a CMS. In this CMS I have the ability to create pages, and this page is managed elsewhere but on this particular page, all you need to do is give it a title.

Would it be better (security wise) to nest the PHP and then call it upon submission in THIS page, or would it be better to define the code in another sheet and call THAT upon submission?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. If the page root is "/some/page", are you asking if it's better to submit to "/some/page" or "/some/otherpage"?

Comment: no, I'm asking is it better to target nested PHP code within the same script as the HTML form, or is it better to target /some/page

Comment: so, do I use target="<?php $_SERVER['PHPSELF']; ?>" or to I use target="some/page.php". I apologise if my question was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling the self page will be fine for other uses like success message kinda. But there is no difference of submitting it to other page or on self submission for security reason.